# Android SimpleDateFormat 'z' format error

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I use codes below, get diffrent result! so how can I fix it?

**in 2.3.5 system, will get**
Thu, 20 Mar 2014 03:11:56 GMT+00:00

**in 4.x system, will get**
Thu, 20 Mar 2014 03:13:28 GMT

```
private static final String RFC822_DATE_FORMAT = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z";

private static DateFormat getRfc822DateFormat() {
SimpleDateFormat rfc822DateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(RFC822_DATE_FORMAT, Locale.US);

rfc822DateFormat.setTimeZone(new SimpleTimeZone(0, "GMT"));

return rfc822DateFormat;
}
```

I fix it like this , but why it cause?

```
 public static String formatRfc822Date(Date date)
 {
String format = getRfc822DateFormat().format(date);
//fix with android 2.3.5 Thu, 20 Mar 2014 03:11:56 GMT+00:00   
if(!format.endsWith("GMT")){
    format = format.substring(0, format.lastIndexOf("+"));  
}
return format;
}
```

Comment: see [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Date-Type/ISO8601ISO8601RFC822Dateformat.htm) may be helpful

Comment: did your problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the `TimeZone` as below...

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0000")
```

instead of as below...

```
new SimpleTimeZone(0, "GMT")
```

Now, pass `TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0000")` as argument through `setTimeZone()` method as follows...

```
rfc822DateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0000"));
```